# reading a string of integers and make an array with them

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

i want to read a string of integers from stdin and then check if everything in the string is integers and then add their value in an int array.I want this to happen until the user decides to stop.In the first loop everything is ok but in the second loop doesnt work, nothing is read and the  "you have to enter only numbers!" is printed and the program exits. maybe the fgets doesnt work? 
Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() 
{
    char str[200], *token, *rest;
    int *numbers;
    int number, size = 0, index=0, i, answer;
    bool hasOnlyNums=true;

        do {
        printf("Enter a sequence of integers: ");
        fgets(str,200,stdin);
        printf("The string you entered is %s\n",str);
        rest = (char*) malloc(200 * sizeof (char));
        strcpy(rest, str);
        numbers = (int *) malloc(sizeof (int));

        while ((token = strtok_r(rest," ", &rest))) {
            if (atoi(token) != 0) {

                size++;
                number = atoi(token);
                numbers = (int *) realloc(numbers, size * sizeof (int));
                *(numbers + index) = number;
                index++;

            } else {
                hasOnlyNums = false;
                break;
            }
        }


        if (!hasOnlyNums) {
            printf("you have to enter only numbers!\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("\nType 0 for exit or any number to continue.\n");
        scanf("%d", &answer);

        free(numbers);
        free(rest);
        size = 0;
        index=0;
        memset(str,0,200);

    } while (answer != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping trough it with a debugger?

Comment: `numbers = (int *) malloc(sizeof (int));` must be `numbers = (int *) malloc(sizeof (int *));` thoughb probably no harm.

Comment: `free(rest);` : `rest` has already been changed.

Comment: You need reset `hasOnlyNums` to `true` before next loop or top of loop..

Comment: `scanf("%d", &answer);` --> `scanf("%d%*c", &answer);`

Comment: thank you the scanf worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of problems here, but the one that's probably stopping you right now is that you are using `strtok_r()` incorrectly.  Try a loop like this:

```
# this variable is for the use of strtok, don't use it for anything else
char *tokstate;

# initialize strtok and get the first token
token = strtok_r(rest, " ", &tokstate);
while(token != NULL) {
    # you got a token
    # do something with token

    # this is the last thing in your loop
    # passing NULL to strtok tells it to continue working on the string
    # you initialized it with.  It has the pointer to where it left off 
    # stored in tokstate so it doesn't need to know about rest anymore. 
    token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &tokstate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of how you're using `strtok_r`.

The first time you call `strtok_r`, the first parameter points to the string to parse.  On subsequent calls, the first parameter should be `NULL`.  Also, you're passing in the address of `rest`, which is the string to parse, for the save pointer.  This modifies `rest` so that when you call `free` it's not pointing to the same place.  It's also not the proper way to use this function, as mentioned above.

You need to use a separate pointer for the third parameter.  Also, you should call `strtok_r` with a non-null first parameter just before the loop, then call it with a null first parameter at the end.

```
char *saveptr;
token = strtok_r(rest," ", &saveptr);
do {
    ...
} while ((token = strtok_r(NULL," ", &saveptr)));
```